# Cómo resolver este problema con el ámbito de variables?

Tags: python, tkinter, variables

En un código que programo para desarrollar un juego de BlackJack tengo un problema con el uso de variables. Dentro del programa tengo una función **main()** dentro de la cual tengo varias funciones. Una de esas funciones, que se usa cuando le doy al botón de **Stand()**, usa una variable que se llama **valor_que_tiene_el_dealer** que se ha declarado dentro de la función **main()** pero fuera de **Stand()**.

El problema es que cuando uso la variable **valor_que_tiene_el_dealer** dentro de la función **Stand()**, de la siguiente forma:

```
 def Stand():

        terminar_de_sacar_cartas_el_dealer = False

        nueva_imagen_carta_2_dealer = tkinter.PhotoImage(file= (str(carta_2_dealer.numero)+".png")).subsample(3)
        label_imagen_carta_2_dealer.configure(image = nueva_imagen_carta_2_dealer)
        label_imagen_carta_2_dealer.image = nueva_imagen_carta_2_dealer 
        i = 2
        if (carta_1_dealer.getBlackJackRank() == 1) or (carta_2_dealer.getBlackJackRank() == 1):
            if (((carta_1_dealer.getBlackJackRank() + carta_2_dealer.getBlackJackRank() - 1) +11) >= 17) and ((((carta_1_dealer.getBlackJackRank() + carta_2_dealer.getBlackJackRank() - 1) +11) <=21)):
                terminar_de_sacar_cartas_el_dealer = True
            
        while (valor_que_tiene_el_dealer < 17) and (terminar_de_sacar_cartas_el_dealer == False):
            carta_nueva_dealer = random.choice(List_of_cards)
            List_of_cards.remove(carta_nueva_dealer) 
            
            nueva_imagen_carta_nueva_dealer = tkinter.PhotoImage(file= (str(carta_nueva_dealer)+".png")).subsample(3)
            
            label_imagen_carta_nueva_dealer = tkinter.Label(zona_Cartas, image = nueva_imagen_carta_nueva_dealer)
            label_imagen_carta_nueva_dealer.grid(row =0, column = i)       
            valor_que_tiene_el_dealer = valor_que_tiene_el_dealer + carta_nueva_dealer.getBlackJackRank()
            i = i + 1
        if valor_que_tiene_el_dealer <=21:
            if valor_que_tiene_el_dealer < valor_que_tiene_el_jugador:
                resultado_money = float(My_money_variable_stringvar.get())
                resultado_pot= float(the_pot_value_stringvar.get())
                resultado_pot = resultado_pot + (resultado_pot*1)
                resultado_money = resultado_money + resultado_pot
                My_money_variable_stringvar.set(resultado_money) 
                the_pot_value_stringvar.set(0)
            else:
                resultado_money = float(My_money_variable_stringvar.get())
                resultado_pot= float(the_pot_value_stringvar.get())
                My_money_variable_stringvar.set(resultado_money) 
                the_pot_value_stringvar.set(0)                
                
        else: 
            resultado_money = float(My_money_variable_stringvar.get())
            resultado_pot= float(the_pot_value_stringvar.get())
            resultado_pot = resultado_pot + (resultado_pot*1)
            resultado_money = resultado_money + resultado_pot
            My_money_variable_stringvar.set(resultado_money) 
            the_pot_value_stringvar.set(0)
```

me salta el siguiente **error**:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'valor_que_tiene_el_dealer'
> referenced before assignment

y si dentro de la función declaro la variable **valor_que_tiene_el_dealer** como global, de la siguiente forma:
def Stand():

```
    terminar_de_sacar_cartas_el_dealer = False
    global valor_que_tiene_el_dealer
    nueva_imagen_carta_2_dealer = tkinter.PhotoImage(file= (str(carta_2_dealer.numero)+".png")).subsample(3)
    label_imagen_carta_2_dealer.configure(image = nueva_imagen_carta_2_dealer)
    label_imagen_carta_2_dealer.image = nueva_imagen_carta_2_dealer 
    i = 2
    if (carta_1_dealer.getBlackJackRank() == 1) or (carta_2_dealer.getBlackJackRank() == 1):
        if (((carta_1_dealer.getBlackJackRank() + carta_2_dealer.getBlackJackRank() - 1) +11) >= 17) and ((((carta_1_dealer.getBlackJackRank() + carta_2_dealer.getBlackJackRank() - 1) +11) <=21)):
            terminar_de_sacar_cartas_el_dealer = True
        
    while (valor_que_tiene_el_dealer < 17) and (terminar_de_sacar_cartas_el_dealer == False):
        carta_nueva_dealer = random.choice(List_of_cards)
        List_of_cards.remove(carta_nueva_dealer) 
        
        nueva_imagen_carta_nueva_dealer = tkinter.PhotoImage(file= (str(carta_nueva_dealer)+".png")).subsample(3)
        
        label_imagen_carta_nueva_dealer = tkinter.Label(zona_Cartas, image = nueva_imagen_carta_nueva_dealer)
        label_imagen_carta_nueva_dealer.grid(row =0, column = i)       
        valor_que_tiene_el_dealer = valor_que_tiene_el_dealer + carta_nueva_dealer.getBlackJackRank()
        i = i + 1
    if valor_que_tiene_el_dealer <=21:
        if valor_que_tiene_el_dealer < valor_que_tiene_el_jugador:
            resultado_money = float(My_money_variable_stringvar.get())
            resultado_pot= float(the_pot_value_stringvar.get())
            resultado_pot = resultado_pot + (resultado_pot*1)
            resultado_money = resultado_money + resultado_pot
            My_money_variable_stringvar.set(resultado_money) 
            the_pot_value_stringvar.set(0)
        else:
            resultado_money = float(My_money_variable_stringvar.get())
            resultado_pot= float(the_pot_value_stringvar.get())
            My_money_variable_stringvar.set(resultado_money) 
            the_pot_value_stringvar.set(0)                
            
    else: 
        resultado_money = float(My_money_variable_stringvar.get())
        resultado_pot= float(the_pot_value_stringvar.get())
        resultado_pot = resultado_pot + (resultado_pot*1)
        resultado_money = resultado_money + resultado_pot
        My_money_variable_stringvar.set(resultado_money) 
        the_pot_value_stringvar.set(0)
```

me salta el siguiente **error**:

> NameError: name 'valor_que_tiene_el_dealer' is not defined

¿Alguien me puede explicar como utilizar la variable **valor_que_tiene_el_dealer** declarada en la función **main()** dentro de la función **Stand()**?

El código completo es el siguiente:

```
import sys
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import os
import random


class Card:
    def __init__(self,numero):
        self.numero = numero
        

    def isFaceDown(self):
        if self.descubierta == True:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def setFaceDown(self):
        self.descubierta = False

        
    def setFaceUp(self):
        self.descubierta = False
        
    def getBlackJackRank(self):
        if ((self.numero == 11) or (self.numero == 12) or (self.numero == 13) or (self.numero == 24) or (self.numero == 25) or (self.numero == 26) or (self.numero == 37) or (self.numero == 38) or (self.numero == 39) or (self.numero == 50) or (self.numero == 51) or (self.numero == 52)):
            return 10
        if ((self.numero == 2) or (self.numero == 15) or (self.numero == 28) or (self.numero == 41)):
            return 2
        if ((self.numero == 3) or (self.numero == 16) or (self.numero == 29) or (self.numero == 42)):
            return 3
        if ((self.numero == 4) or (self.numero == 17) or (self.numero == 30) or (self.numero == 43)):
            return 4
        if ((self.numero == 5) or (self.numero == 18) or (self.numero == 31) or (self.numero == 44)):
            return 5
        if ((self.numero == 6) or (self.numero == 19) or (self.numero == 32) or (self.numero == 45)):
            return 6
        if ((self.numero == 7) or (self.numero == 20) or (self.numero == 33) or (self.numero == 46)):
            return 7
        if ((self.numero == 8) or (self.numero == 21) or (self.numero == 34) or (self.numero == 47)):
            return 8
        if ((self.numero == 9) or (self.numero == 22) or (self.numero == 35) or (self.numero == 48)):
            return 9
        if ((self.numero == 10) or (self.numero == 23) or (self.numero == 36) or (self.numero == 49)):
            return  10
        if ((self.numero == 1) or (self.numero == 14) or (self.numero == 27) or (self.numero == 40)):
            return 1
     
def main():
  
  
    def Hit():
        global empieza_la_partida
     
  
        if empieza_la_partida ==  True:
      
            #nada mas empezar hay que hacer la apuesta mínima de 5 (abajo)
            resultado_money = float(My_money_variable_stringvar.get())-5
            resultado_pot= float(the_pot_value_stringvar.get()) + 5
            My_money_variable_stringvar.set(resultado_money) 
            the_pot_value_stringvar.set(resultado_pot)            
            #nada mas empezar hay que hacer la apuesta mínima de 5 (arriba)
            nueva_imagen_carta_1_jugador = tkinter.PhotoImage(file= (str(carta_1_jugador.numero)+".png")).subsample(3)
            nueva_imagen_carta_2_jugador = tkinter.PhotoImage(file= (str(carta_2_jugador.numero)+".png")).subsample(3)
            nueva_imagen_carta_1_dealer =  tkinter.PhotoImage(file= (str(carta_1_dealer.numero)+".png")).subsample(3)
            
            label_imagen_carta_1_jugador.configure(image = nueva_imagen_carta_1_jugador)
            label_imagen_carta_1_jugador.image = nueva_imagen_carta_1_jugador
            label_imagen_carta_2_jugador.configure(image =nueva_imagen_carta_2_jugador)
            label_imagen_carta_2_jugador.image = nueva_imagen_carta_2_jugador
            label_imagen_carta_1_dealer.configure(image = nueva_imagen_carta_1_dealer)
            label_imagen_carta_1_dealer.image = nueva_imagen_carta_1_dealer
            
        empieza_la_partida = False  
        
        
        #Caso de que tenga BlackJack
        if valor_que_tiene_el_jugador == 11:
            resultado_money = float(My_money_variable_stringvar.get())
            resultado_pot= float(the_pot_value_stringvar.get())
            resultado_pot = resultado_pot + (resultado_pot*(3/2))
            resultado_money = resultado_money + resultado_pot
            My_money_variable_stringvar.set(resultado_money) 
            the_pot_value_stringvar.set(0)                   
            
       
    def Stand():

        terminar_de_sacar_cartas_el_dealer = False
        global valor_que_tiene_el_dealer
        nueva_imagen_carta_2_dealer = tkinter.PhotoImage(file= (str(carta_2_dealer.numero)+".png")).subsample(3)
        label_imagen_carta_2_dealer.configure(image = nueva_imagen_carta_2_dealer)
        label_imagen_carta_2_dealer.image = nueva_imagen_carta_2_dealer 
        i = 2
        if (carta_1_dealer.getBlackJackRank() == 1) or (carta_2_dealer.getBlackJackRank() == 1):
            if (((carta_1_dealer.getBlackJackRank() + carta_2_dealer.getBlackJackRank() - 1) +11) >= 17) and ((((carta_1_dealer.getBlackJackRank() + carta_2_dealer.getBlackJackRank() - 1) +11) <=21)):
                terminar_de_sacar_cartas_el_dealer = True
            
        while (valor_que_tiene_el_dealer < 17) and (terminar_de_sacar_cartas_el_dealer == False):
            carta_nueva_dealer = random.choice(List_of_cards)
            List_of_cards.remove(carta_nueva_dealer) 
            
            nueva_imagen_carta_nueva_dealer = tkinter.PhotoImage(file= (str(carta_nueva_dealer)+".png")).subsample(3)
            
            label_imagen_carta_nueva_dealer = tkinter.Label(zona_Cartas, image = nueva_imagen_carta_nueva_dealer)
            label_imagen_carta_nueva_dealer.grid(row =0, column = i)       
            valor_que_tiene_el_dealer = valor_que_tiene_el_dealer + carta_nueva_dealer.getBlackJackRank()
            i = i + 1
        if valor_que_tiene_el_dealer <=21:
            if valor_que_tiene_el_dealer < valor_que_tiene_el_jugador:
                resultado_money = float(My_money_variable_stringvar.get())
                resultado_pot= float(the_pot_value_stringvar.get())
                resultado_pot = resultado_pot + (resultado_pot*1)
                resultado_money = resultado_money + resultado_pot
                My_money_variable_stringvar.set(resultado_money) 
                the_pot_value_stringvar.set(0)
            else:
                resultado_money = float(My_money_variable_stringvar.get())
                resultado_pot= float(the_pot_value_stringvar.get())
                My_money_variable_stringvar.set(resultado_money) 
                the_pot_value_stringvar.set(0)                
                
        else: 
            resultado_money = float(My_money_variable_stringvar.get())
            resultado_pot= float(the_pot_value_stringvar.get())
            resultado_pot = resultado_pot + (resultado_pot*1)
            resultado_money = resultado_money + resultado_pot
            My_money_variable_stringvar.set(resultado_money) 
            the_pot_value_stringvar.set(0)              
            
        
        
        
    def Bet_5():
      
        
        if float(My_money_variable_stringvar.get()) < 5:
            print("No funds")
        else:
            resultado_money = float(My_money_variable_stringvar.get())-5
            resultado_pot= float(the_pot_value_stringvar.get()) + 5
            My_money_variable_stringvar.set(resultado_money) 
            the_pot_value_stringvar.set(resultado_pot)
        
    def Bet_10():
        
        if float(My_money_variable_stringvar.get()) < 10:
            print("No funds")
        else:
            resultado_money = float(My_money_variable_stringvar.get())-10
            resultado_pot= float(the_pot_value_stringvar.get()) + 10
            My_money_variable_stringvar.set(resultado_money) 
            the_pot_value_stringvar.set(resultado_pot)
            
    #defino la interfaz abajo
    
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    
    root.title("Black Jack")
    root.resizable(width=True,height=True)
    bar = tkinter.Menu(root)
    
    fileMenu = tkinter.Menu(bar,tearoff=0)
    fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit",command=root.quit)
    bar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=fileMenu)
    root.config(menu=bar)
    
    cardsFrame = tkinter.Frame(root,borderwidth=1,padx=5,pady=5)
    cardsFrame.pack()
    
    entryFrame = tkinter.Frame(cardsFrame)
    entryFrame.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)
    
    zona_Cartas = tkinter.Frame(cardsFrame)
    zona_Cartas.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
    
    tkinter.Button(entryFrame,text="Hit", command=Hit).grid( row =0 , column =0, columnspan = 2)
    
    tkinter.Button(entryFrame,text="Stand", command=Stand).grid( row =1 ,  column =0, columnspan = 2)
    
    tkinter.Button(entryFrame,text="Bet $5", command=Bet_5).grid( row =2 ,  column =0, columnspan = 2)
    
    tkinter.Button(entryFrame,text="Bet $10", command=Bet_10).grid( row =3 ,  column =0, columnspan = 2)  
    
    if empieza_la_partida == True:
        the_pot_value = 0
        My_money_variable = float(input("Please enter the money you want to start with: "))
        the_pot_value_stringvar = tkinter.StringVar()
        My_money_variable_stringvar = tkinter.StringVar()        
        the_pot_value_stringvar.set(the_pot_value)
        My_money_variable_stringvar.set(My_money_variable)        
    
    My_money_Label = tkinter . Label (entryFrame, text ="My Money")
    My_money_Label . grid ( row =4 , column =0 )
        
    My_money_value = tkinter . Label (entryFrame, textvariable=My_money_variable_stringvar)
    My_money_value . grid ( row =4 , column =1 )    
    
    
    The_Pot_Label = tkinter . Label (entryFrame , text ="The Pot")
    The_Pot_Label . grid ( row =5 , column =0)
    
    The_Pot_value = tkinter . Label (entryFrame , textvariable =the_pot_value_stringvar)
    The_Pot_value . grid ( row =5 , column =1 )    
    
    Card_Totals_Label = tkinter . Label ( entryFrame , text ="Card Totals")
    Card_Totals_Label . grid ( row =6 , column =0 , columnspan = 2)
    
    Player_Label = tkinter . Label ( entryFrame , text ="Player")
    Player_Label . grid ( row =7 , column =0 )
    

    Player_value = tkinter . Label ( entryFrame)
    Player_value . grid ( row =7 , column =1 )    
    
    Dealer_Label = tkinter . Label ( entryFrame , text ="Dealer")
    Dealer_Label . grid ( row =8 , column =0 )
    
    Dealer_value = tkinter . Label ( entryFrame)
    Dealer_value . grid ( row =8 , column =1 )    
    
    List_of_cards = list(range(1,52))
    
    #reparto las dos cartas al jugador
    carta_1_jugador = random.choice(List_of_cards)
    List_of_cards.remove(carta_1_jugador)
    carta_2_jugador = random.choice(List_of_cards)
    List_of_cards.remove(carta_2_jugador)
    #reparto las dos cartas al dealer
    carta_1_dealer = random.choice(List_of_cards)
    List_of_cards.remove(carta_1_dealer)
    carta_2_dealer = random.choice(List_of_cards)
    List_of_cards.remove(carta_2_dealer) 
    
    if empieza_la_partida ==  True:
    
        #inserto las imagenes de las cartas
        
        imagen_carta_1_jugador = (tkinter.PhotoImage(file="parte_de_atras.png")).subsample(3)
        imagen_carta_2_jugador = (tkinter.PhotoImage(file="parte_de_atras.png")).subsample(3)
        imagen_carta_1_dealer = (tkinter.PhotoImage(file="parte_de_atras.png")).subsample(3)
        imagen_carta_2_dealer = (tkinter.PhotoImage(file="parte_de_atras.png")).subsample(3)
        
        imagen_carta_a_repartir = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="parte_de_atras.png").subsample(3)
        
        
        

    #genero variables de tipo stringvar para las imagenes (abajo)
    

    
    #genero variables de tipo stringvar para las imagenes (arriba)
    
    
    
    
    
    label_imagen_carta_1_jugador = tkinter.Label(zona_Cartas, image = imagen_carta_1_jugador)
    label_imagen_carta_1_jugador.grid(row =2, column = 0)

    
    label_imagen_carta_2_jugador = tkinter.Label(zona_Cartas, image = imagen_carta_2_jugador)
    label_imagen_carta_2_jugador.grid(row =2, column = 1)

    
    label_imagen_carta_1_dealer = tkinter.Label(zona_Cartas, image = imagen_carta_1_dealer)
    label_imagen_carta_1_dealer.grid(row =0, column = 0)

    label_imagen_carta_2_dealer = tkinter.Label(zona_Cartas, image = imagen_carta_2_dealer)
    label_imagen_carta_2_dealer.grid(row =0, column = 1)   
    

    label_imagen_carta_a_repartir = tkinter.Label(zona_Cartas, image = imagen_carta_a_repartir)
    label_imagen_carta_a_repartir.grid(row =1, column = 0)    
    
    
    
    carta_1_jugador = Card(carta_1_jugador)
    carta_2_jugador = Card(carta_2_jugador)
    carta_1_dealer = Card(carta_1_dealer)
    carta_2_dealer = Card(carta_2_dealer)
    
  
    
    valor_que_tiene_el_jugador = carta_1_jugador.getBlackJackRank() + carta_2_jugador.getBlackJackRank()
    valor_que_tiene_el_dealer = carta_1_dealer.getBlackJackRank() + carta_2_dealer.getBlackJackRank()
    
    
#defino la interfaz arriba
    

    
    def appClosing():
        
        root.destroy()
        root.quit()
        sys.exit()    
    
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", appClosing)  
    
        
    root.mainloop()    
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numero_de_carta_del_jugador = 3
    numero_de_carta_del_dealer = 3
    
    empieza_la_partida = True
    main()
```

Comment: Has probado inicializar valor_que_tiene_el_dealer = 0 (no digo que sea exactamente eso toda la solución, pero es uno de los motivos porque da error)

Comment: @MarceloZárate pero eso no soluciona nada. Porque quiero que la variable valor_que_tiene_el_dealer almacene un número, y que sea asignado dentro de main(), pero fuera de Stand().

Comment: *se ha declarado dentro de la función main() pero fuera de Stand()* Tu mismo estás diciendo que **no** se trata de una variable global (es decir, una variable fuera de toda función). Esa es una variable no local. Prueba usar la sentencia nonlocal en lugar de global.